# XQuery Regular Expression

Tags: regex, semantics, rdf, sparql

Given the string/uri http://www.HomeBaseLine.com/Records#First_Class , I need to write a regular expression for the above string that filters all such strings for the one that contains the word First_Class(case insensitive) in XQuery regular expression language. I have used

```
"^First_Class" 

"^First_Class^" 

"/First_Class/"
```

but none of those seems to work. Thanks for your help

Comment: You might want to consider that RDF databases tend to be very poor wrt to evaluation of regex filters.  You can't specify indexes for them to create, so these types of filters tend to be evaluated for every solution set in every query and can lead to very poor performance for queries which are unselected or have unselected intermediate joins.  Some databases integrate Lucene, or lucene-like systems to defer these sorts of filters to the subsystem which leads to far better performance.  But in general, you might want to consider avoiding use of regex in a query filter.

Answer (score 1):

Using the str("First_Class") function does the trick in SPARQL.